# check if a char exists in a char 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to check if a character belongs to a two dimensional array of characters, but my code doesn't work right for all characters. I think that something goes wrong with my pointer.For example if i change 'b' to 'r' it doesn't work correctly.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *pch;
    char matrix[2][2]={
        "best","cover",
        "orbit","boost"
    };
    pch=strchr(matrix,'b');
    if (pch==NULL)
    {
        printf ("not exists");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("exists");
      }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Incorrect matrix creation, I think

Comment: You want two dimensional character array, or two dimensional string array?

Comment: In C the general advice is to avoid 2D arrays, and always use 1D arrays, perhaps as [flexible array members](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems in your code.

1. You need to include `<stdio.h>` in order to use `printf`.
2. There isn't enough memory allocated here:

   ```
   char matrix[2][2]={
   "best","cover",
   "orbit","boost"
   };
   ```

   You give space for two strings each of which can hold 1 character(+1 for the NUL-terminator at the end).
   Fix it by using:

   ```
   char matrix[4][6]={
   "best","cover",
   "orbit","boost"
   };
   ```

   The six is the maximum number of characters in a string + one for the `\0` at the end and the four is the number of maximum number of strings in the 2D array.
3. `strchr` expects the first argument to be of type `const char*`. You give the argument `matrix` which is of type `char(*)[2]`. You need to loop and find if the character is in each string of the array of array of `char`s.

After fixing these problems, your code will be:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // Not required
#include <string.h> // For strchr()
#include <stdio.h> // For printf()

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *pch;
    char matrix[4][6]={
        "best","cover",
        "orbit","boost"
    };
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        pch=strchr(matrix[i],'b');

        if (pch==NULL)
        {
          printf ("not exists in %s\n",matrix[i]);
        }
        else
        {
          printf("exists in %s\n",matrix[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char matrix[2][6]` -> `char matrix[4][6]` ?

Comment: `char matrix[2][6]` (or `[4][6]`, for that matter) is wrong I think, the array initialiser and "2 dimensional" in question title seem like the OP wants a two-dimensional array of `char*`.

Comment: @schnaader Well, OP says "*a two dimensional array of characters*", but I am not sure if OP themselves know what they want...

Comment: @schnaader , But the code snippet shows `char matrix[2][2]` which indicates that the OP wants a 2D array `char matrix[4][6]` instead of `char* matrix[4]`

Comment: I thought he wants `char* matrix[2][2]`. Anyway, luk32 asked him, so perhaps we'll get a clarification.

Comment: @schnaader , I too support luk32 and think that the OP doesn't know what is what and what he/she wants.